# Spark - WARN LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded

Tags: pyspark, snappy

Trying to run an exercise from [Spark Summit 2014](https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/movie-recommendation-with-mllib.html). I keep getting the following when running the command in terminal:

```
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; 
support was removed in 8.0
15/04/26 14:21:05 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library 
for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/04/26 14:21:05 WARN LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
```

I found online that the first NativeCodeLoader warning is expected on MACs. What about the second one? How can I get Snappy loaded?

Thanks!

Edit: As is, the code runs, generates the above output and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid that warning by installing the snappy libraries and placed it in your classpath if you are running a simple Map Reduce program. You can download the jar from here https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java/1.1.1.2.

OR if you are using Maven project, then you have to add this dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
  <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1.7</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Those warnings are expected in a OSX environment. Verify that you have followed the steps in the tutorial correctly. To see any output you need to update the original MovieLensALS.scala file.

Add the following code below the "// your code here" comment.

```
val numRatings = ratings.count
val numUsers = ratings.map(_._2.user).distinct.count
val numMovies = ratings.map(_._2.product).distinct.count

println("Got " + numRatings + " ratings from "
  + numUsers + " users on " + numMovies + " movies.")
```